# Awards for math.SE community?

Tags: discussion

I have one strange idea. Is it a good idea to have something  like Oscar awards for math.SE annually for excellence in different categories. We may not give money but just the titles give a lot of recognition and fun.

Comment: That sounds horrible.

Comment: Wow looks like i am unknowingly  contesting for the question on meta with highest number of down votes!

Comment: There was an attempt to start voting process for favorite questions and answers for 1 quarter - [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10356/favorite-questions-and-answers-from-2nd-quarter-of-2013) is a 10k+ link. It was suggested in [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10351/star-ranking-system). One of the comments there mentions, that there exists something like that at [scifi.SE](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/favorite-questions-and-answers-from-2nd-quarter-of-2013).

Comment: I like the idea, but to make it really like the Oscars etc... we need to create a bunch of categories nobody cares about and where the chance to win an award is at least say 1/3.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that this is a good idea. People already get worked up enough about reputation, I think that giving out awards would only increase the amount of "competitive" behaviour on the site, which is not what it's about at all.

Do we need awards to recognise consistently excellent answers? The main reason I'm against the idea is that there is already a system in place for this. It's already possible to track the reputation earned for each tag, and there are a number of badges which provide a "reward" for good work in any given area (of question answering). Similarly with things such as the review queue, editing, flagging, etc. All desired "excellent" behaviour seems to have a badge already.

The only other reason I can think of to give out awards would be for the fun of doing it. I don't disagree with this on principle, but it could possibly by seen as making the tone of the site less serious. One of the arguments against PSQ was that it made the site less professional. I recall that some users didn't want to tell colleagues of the investment they'd put into the site and had stopped recommending it to colleagues. Others simply didn't like the idea of a "less professional" atmosphere for personal reasons. Either way, I imagine any sort of awards system would have a similar response.